# Accessing Spark SQL RDD tables through the Thrift Server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have registered a temporary table with Spark SQL, as described in [[this section]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection):

```
people.registerTempTable("people")
// I can run queries on it all right.
val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
```

Now I want to access this table remotely through JDBC. I start up the Thrift Server as described in [[this other section]](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbc-server).

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://same-master-as-above:7077
```

But the table is not visible.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show tables;         
+---------+
| result  |
+---------+
+---------+
No rows selected (2.216 seconds)
```

I guess this is because the table is "temporary" (i.e. tied to the lifetime of the `SqlContext` object). But how do I make non-temporary tables?

I can see [Hive tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables) through the Thrift Server, but I don't see how I could expose an RDD like this. I've found [a comment](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/42389b1780311d90499b4ce2315ceabf5b6ab384/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala#L309) that suggests I cannot.

Or should I run the Thrift Server in my application with my own `SqlContext`? Almost all classes around it are `private`, and this code is not in Maven Central (as far as I see). Am I supposed to use `HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext`? It's undocumented and `@DeveloperApi`, but might work.

Comment: did you find a workable answer for this?

Comment: when using pyspark its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `spark-defaults.conf` and add `spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession true`.

This allows the Thrift server to see temp tables based directly on RDD without having to save the table.  You can also do `CACHE TABLE XXX AS <query>` in Spark SQL and have it be exposed via ODBC/JDBC.

Answer (score 17):

Most probably you have already solved this problem.
But I tried a similar use case recently and wanted to share my findings.
To expose Spark data over JDBC, you need to do the following:

- Start the thrift-server that comes with Spark (I used version 1.3.1), the thrift-server with Hive might as well work but I haven't tested that

  /opt/mapr/spark/spark-1.3.1/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master spark://spark-master:7077 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.bind.host spark-master --hiveconf hive.server2.trift.port 10001

Ensure you don't give "localhost" but the actual ip-address/dnsname of the server to "hive.server2.thrift.bind.host", otherwise you cant connect to this thrift server from a different host

- beeline is a simple JDBC client that comes with Hive & Spark. Start beeline and connect it to your thrift server

SPARK_HOME/bin/beeline

beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://spark-master:10001

- you can use any hiveql here to load the data you want into a table, but the sql will be executed in Spark cluster

  create temporary table tweets using org.apache.spark.sql.parquet options (path 'maprfs:///path-to-your-parquet-files/');
- cache the table in spark memory

cache table tweets

- thats it, all your data is now cached in the spark cluster and you can query this with low latency over remote jdbc
- the jdbc coding is exactly the same as writing any hive jdbc code because the thrift server understand the hiveql and translates that to spark sql behind. Look here for hive jdbc examples:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-ConnectionURLs

For username, you can give any linux username in the thrift-server machine and leave password blank (this is non-secured mode, you can make things more secured if needed)

- the table "tweets" will not be visible with "show tables" etc because the table is not registered in the hive metastore but you can do all sql queries with the table over jdbc
- you can use Spark to cache data in memory and query that over remote jdbc/odbc. This will yield low latency responses, I got <2 secs responses for data size of about 40 GB. But, the caching will not work for really big data, like tera bytes. In that case, avoid the "cache table ..." command and you can still use the remote jdbc/odbc, but responses will not be in the low latency range

All the best!

MK

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of useful detail! What is missing though is that I cannot just start the Thriftserver from the command line. I have some Spark RDD that I want to make accessible via JDBC. So I need the Thriftserver to use the SparkContext of my running Spark application. I haven't yet tried `HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext`, but when I do your instructions will be very helpful!

Comment: @user1158559: Nope, sorry. It turned out we had no practical use case for this after all, so I did not pursue it further.

Comment: Thanks. Just to let anyone reading this know, I got it working after posting that comment. The temporary tables are per SQL session, so you need to enable spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession in order to share them with your SQL clients. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-15-to-16

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628918/start-hivethriftserver-programmatically-in-python cannot access the temptables created in python

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly we should "make things more secured"? i.e. how can we have proper user/pass authentication in thrift server without Kerberos?

Answer (score 3):

From [SPARK-3675](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3675):

> A common question on the mailing list is how to read from temporary tables over JDBC. While we should try and support most of this in SQL, it would also be nice to query generic RDDs over JDBC.

And the solution (coming in Spark 1.2.0) is indeed to use `HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext`.

Comment: How to use HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext

Comment: from pyspark.sql.hive.thriftserver import HiveThriftServer2
is not available in pyspark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628918/start-hivethriftserver-programmatically-in-python

Answer (score 3):

The general idea behind a temp table, at least from the original RDBMS intention is that it has very limited scope, usually the user session, and goes out of scope & is cleaned up when the session ends.

If you create a temp table in one session, then another session that connects via JDBC or ODBC to the thriftserver is not going to be able to see it, and that's by design. If you need a table to persist beyond a session then it's not temporary by definition.

The solution suggested to "enable spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession in order to share them with your SQL clients" works yes, but kind of defeats the purpose of having a multi-session environment. Setting single session is effectively forcing temp tables to behave as persistent tables, except they will still go out of context if the hive meta-store restarts.

It's easy enough to use the SqlContext to CREATE TABLE, or use saveAsTable() see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables

EDIT, It appears saveAsTable is mentioned first in the spark 1.3 documentation, but you can use the inlineSQL method if you are on an earlier version.

```
people.write.saveAsTable("people")
```

That will persist the people table in your default database. Better to create a database first and specify it:

```
people.write.saveAsTable("databaseName.people")
```

or with inline SQL

```
sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people
as SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
```

Both of those methods will register the persistent table in the hive metastore. saveAsTable also has options as to whether you want to append or overwrite