# How can I make my pyspark database visible to beeline on windows?

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, beeline, spark-thriftserver

**Hey All,** I need some help to open a pickle jar in pyspark. I'm learning pyspark and as an exercise I'm trying to do something that I assumed would be a simple thing... but its giving me a very hard time.

So let's start with what I'm doing. I'm working with windows and I'm trying to start a local thrift server and connect via beeline to a database I created within my app in a spark session.

```
::step1 - start master in cmd
start %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

**Step 1 works great** and I can see the master server spark://n.n.n.n:7077 created with my spark 2.3.2. in localhost:8080.

```
::step2 - start worker in cmd
start %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-class.cmd org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://n.n.n.n:7077
```

**So far so good** and I can see I have a worker alive with 8 cores running.

```
::step3 - start thrift server
start %SPARK_HOME%\bin\spark-submit.cmd --verbose --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 spark-internal --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --master spark://n.n.n.n:7077 --total-executor-cores 4
```

**Step 3 ok, I can see the SparkSQL application running** and I can even connect to it via beeline!

```
::if I do
start %SPARK_HOME%\bin\beeline.cmd

Beeline version 1.2.1.spark2 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: username
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: password

Connected to: Spark SQL (version 2.3.2)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1.spark2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> SHOW TABLES;
+-----------+------------+--------------+--+
| database  | tableName  | isTemporary  |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--+
+-----------+------------+--------------+--+
```

**Final Step: create my app and feed it to my spark master** I now go to jupiter-notebook to run my application with:

```
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("Publish a database attempt").master("spark://n.n.n.n:7077").config('spark.sql.warehouse.dir','file:///D:/tmp/SparkDatabase/').getOrCreate()
df1=spark.read.csv('C:/data.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df1.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('testTable')

spark.sql('show tables in default').show()
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|database|  tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| default|  testTable|      false|
+--------+-----------+-----------+

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testTable").show()
+--------+--------+--------+
| column1| column2| column3|
+--------+--------+--------+
|      hi|   there|  friend|
+--------+--------+--------+
```

**This is when the spark hits the fan...** I can see this database in my application session but its not showing with beeline. Going back to beeline and doing another SHOW TABLES; Don't do the trick.

**Comments:**

1. I noticed that when I start the thrift server it creates a metastore_db and this doesn't happen when I create my application from jupiter notebook.
2. If I try to create my application from a pyspark instance instead of jupyter-notebook I get a ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby running.

**What I'm trying to achieve here is just to be able to see and query my table via beeline in windows as an exercise.** Would really appreciate the help with that pickle jar.

using: *conda 4.5.12; Python 3.6.5; PySpark 2.3.2; hadoop-3.0.0*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found another question in stackoverflow that contains a way to solve my issue and I can consider as an answer: 
[Start HiveThriftServer programmatically in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628918)

Essentially I need to forget about step 3 and run my application in Jupyter-notebook with:

```
from pyspark import *
from pyspark.sql import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
 .appName('Hi there') \
 .master('spark://n.n.n.n:7077') \
 .enableHiveSupport() \
 .config('spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession', True) \
 .getOrCreate()

#Start the Thrift Server using the jvm and passing the same spark session corresponding to pyspark session in the jvm side.
spark.sparkContext._gateway.jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(spark._jwrapped) 

df1=spark.read.csv('C:/data.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df1.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('testTable')
```

That way I will start the Thrift Server using the java for the current session. With that, I can easily connect to all my tables and access the data with beeline or other odbc connector.